# What are the Blockchain Transactions Status possible values?

Tags: transactions

Very noob at this.
I'm seeing that a transaction in Bitcoin has a field called 'status':

Example from [blockchain](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d390350a8f6f7af2259ff69fda08b91087656af18c3f03ec0f826e6345c1bb65):

[image]

I was wondering, what are all the possible values that this field can get (or where to search for them)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know. As an approximation, we can look at what's written in Bitcoin Core:

```
/** New transactions start as UNCONFIRMED. At BlockConnected,
 * they will transition to CONFIRMED. In case of reorg, at BlockDisconnected,
 * they roll back to UNCONFIRMED. If we detect a conflicting transaction at
 * block connection, we update conflicted tx and its dependencies as CONFLICTED.
 * If tx isn't confirmed and outside of mempool, the user may switch it to ABANDONED
 * by using the abandontransaction call. This last status may be override by a CONFLICTED
 * or CONFIRMED transition.
 */
enum Status {
    UNCONFIRMED,
    CONFIRMED,
    CONFLICTED,
    ABANDONED
};
```

Source: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/571bb94dfb5047c9be8fcbae5dae71de7256b86c/src/wallet/transaction.h#L148-L153

Comment: I'm very unsure that these are the exact same possibilities that blockchain.info uses.